# Youtube Data Api Authorization at Windows Service get timeout

Tags: c#, windows-services, youtube-data-api

I develop an little C# application for timed Youtube-uploads.
I've a UI WPF application which should communicate via WCF with a background-service.
This background-service does everything which has to do with Youtube.

I realized the background-service as windows-service which work properly.

However if the windows service try to get credentials, I'm running into a WCF- timeout. As far as i debug the problem, after calling:

```
using(var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            _credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[]{YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

nothing happens. Normally would appear a browser-window to give the application access (which it does if I does the same in a normal application).

Has this to do with the access-level of the windows-service?  I've use `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem`.

For clearance:
the whole WCF and youtube code work properly if I implemented it in a normal console-application, but in a windows service it timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var _credential = await 
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(UriFromRelativePath(this, "/API/client_secret.json"), new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None);


public static Uri UriFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);

            return uri;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` has no overload which take a Uri? I'm using Youtube-Data-Api v3